# Java looping (do and while) trouble

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Here is a fair amount of code that I attempted to program but what else is needed to finish this up I need the end result to do this:

> Compile and run your program with following inputs (Provide output of
>   your program) a)  First product as “Bicycle Horn” with unit price as
>   “7.19”, quantity as “2”, and manufacturer as “Klout”. b)  Second
>   product as “Forerunner Watch” with unit price as “140.89”, quantity as
>   “2”, and manufacturer as “Garmin”.
>
> And a Sample OUTPUT is supposed to look like this:
>
> Product               Unit Price  Quantity    SubTotal Klout Bicycle Horn         $7.19
>   2     $14.38 Garmin Forerunner Watch          $140.89     2       $281.78

```
//***************************************************************

// import statements

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

//Class header

public class ShoppingCart {

    // Start of main method

    public static <Item> void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare and instantiate a variable that is an ArrayList that can hold
        // Product objects

        ArrayList<Product> item = new ArrayList<Product>();

        // Declare necessary local variables here

        String Name = null;
        double Price = 0;
        int Quantity = 0;
        String Seller = null;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Shop = "yes";

        // Write a print statement that welcome's the customer to our shop

        /**
         * 
         * create a do while that will be keep looping as long as user wants to
         * continue shopping
         */

        Product item1 = new Product(Name, Price, Quantity, Seller);

        // do while loop start

        do {

            // Ask user to enter product name and store it in appropriate local
            // variable

            System.out.print("Please Enter the Product Name: ");

            Name = scan.next();

            // Ask user to enter product price and store it in appropriate local
            // variable

            System.out.print("Please Enter the Price of the Product: ");

            Price = scan.nextDouble();

            // Ask user to enter quantity and store it in appropriate local
            // variable

            System.out.print("Please enter the Quantity: ");

            Quantity = scan.nextInt();

            // Ask user to enter product manufacturer name and store it in
            // appropriate local variable

            System.out.print("Please Enter the Manufacturer: ");

            Seller = scan.next();

            System.out.print("Would you like to continue shopping?");

            Shop = scan.next();

            // create a new Product object using above inputed values

            Product newitem = new Product(Name, Price, Quantity, Seller);

            // add above created Product to the ArrayList cart if Product has
            // available stock

            // if stock not available inform user requested product is out of
            // stock

            // Ask user whether wants to continue shopping

            // set the do while loop to continue to loop if Yes option is
            // selected

        } while (Shop.equals(Shop));
        {
            if (Shop == null) {
                break;
            }

            // do while loop end
            // header for shopping cart contents
            // print details of each product added to the ArrayList
            // calculate total price of the shopping cart
            // print the total price of the shopping cart
        }

    }// end of main method

}// end of Shop class



//***************************************************************
//Product.java
//Represents an item in a shopping cart.
//***************************************************************
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Product
{
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private double subtotal;
    private String manufacturer;
    private int inventory;

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create a new item with the given attributes.
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    public Product (String name, double price, int quantity, String manufacturer)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;

        subtotal = price*quantity;

        inventory = 10;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    //   Return a string with the information about the Product
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString ()
    {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        /*
        String item;
        if (name.length() >= 8)
            item = name + "\t";
        else
            item = name + "\t\t";
            */
        return (manufacturer + " " + name + "\t\t    " + fmt.format(price) + "\t    " + quantity 
                + "\t\t" + fmt.format(subtotal));
    }

    //   Returns the unit price of the Product
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    //   Returns the name of the Product
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    //   Returns the quantity of the Product
    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    //   Returns the sub total of the Product
    public double getSubTotal()
    {
        return subtotal;
    }

    // Returns product manufacturer
    public String getManufacturer()
    {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    // Checks whether product is in stock
    // if after inventory get below stock after processing order, then
    // places order to replenish stock
    public boolean checkInventory()
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (inventory > quantity)
        {
            flag = true;
            inventory = inventory - quantity;

            if (inventory <= 0)
                placeOrder(quantity);
        }

        return flag;
    }

    // Replenishes stock to 10 times the quantity of last order
    private void placeOrder(int orderQuantity)
    {
        inventory = orderQuantity * 10;
    }
}//end of class Item
```

Comment: What's the problem? If it's to "finish it up", have you tried finishing it up?

Comment: Perhaps you have to put the `if` clause inside the `do-while` loop.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi there is a problem executing the program when trying to stop asking for products and then producing an output. There is a second class that this is supposed to go along with which I recently edited the post and added it in.

Comment: @Nicholaslane You're going to need to clarify, and perhaps reduce the code into something that succinctly exhibits the problem. Ideally we shouldn't have to run your code to understand what's wrong.

Comment: What´s the breaking condition?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi when ever this runs and it prompts me for inputs it works just fine then it asks would you like to continue and regargless of how a try to make the response stop it from running it continues to run. Im sure Im just extremely tired and over looking something silly but I need to know why even when " shop.equals" is set to no it doesn't hault and then hop out of the loop

Comment: when shop is equal what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting Shop on the first iteration of the loop. Which means Shop will always be equal to Shop which will break the loop. I'm assuming that the intended logic is to check if the scan that overwrites shop is equal to "yes". If so then make the while loop check Shop.equals("yes"). For future reference, please include more information in your question such as what work have you done, what the problem actually is, and include classes that are required so that others can run the program without much hassle.